# Ionic Headers Failing to set through http.post

Tags: angular, ionic3

```
return this.http.post(this.url + '/' + endpoint, body, {headers: {
      'customHeader1': 'changed',
      'customHeader2': 'changed2'       
    }});
```

The above snippet is my http request. I can make the call without the headers object, however the endpoint I'm calling won't return data until I set those headers. Adding those headers caused the app to return the below error:

```
    user.ts:50 ERROR TypeError: req.headers.forEach is not a function
```

How can I resolve this and set my headers in the http request?

These are my imports

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptionsArgs, RequestMethod, Headers, Request 
} from '@angular/http';
```

This is my constructor

```
constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually create an options object with the 'headers'

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers });
```

and then use it

```
this.http.post(this.url + '/' + endpoint, body, options)
```

as explained here: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-http-post-example

Comment: Fixed the error I was getting, but the headers do not set in the request